# CakePHP Call to a member function getResponse() on a non-object

Tags: cakephp, datatables

Hello i am using cakephp 2.0

I am using jquery dataTable for get data.

I am getting this error  `Call to a member function getResponse() on a non-object`  when i am using  `$this->DataTable->getResponse()`

I have paste file into app\Controller\Component\DataTableComponent.php

Comment: Look the error message up on Google, this is a *basic* php issue and I think the message is more than clear to understand. So figure out why you're trying to call a method on a non-object.

Comment: Did you use App::uses  to include class? If yes is the method getResponse() belong to the class you have included ?

Comment: public $components = array('DataTable'); 
M  added this line and its work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `helper('dataTable')` into your controller.